# Rails4 Scope or default_scope deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

While upgrading to Rails4 from 3.2, I am getting a deprecation warning as

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Returning a hash from a #scope or #default_scope
>   block is deprecated. Please return an actual scope object instead.
>   E.g. scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') } rather than scope :red, ->
>   { { conditions: { color: 'red' } } }. (The scope was defined at
>   /Users/newimac/RailsApp/bank/app/models/account.rb:101.). (called from
>   **pry** at (pry):18)

When running this Query

```
Account.need_processing(current)
```

And

```
Account.need_processing(@current).should be_empty
```

And I have defined `scope` in Rails 3.2 as:

```
scope :need_processing, lambda {|cutoff| {:conditions => ["state = 'active' and processed_through < ?", cutoff.ago(1.day)]}}
```

After upgrading to Rails 4.0.4. I have defined `scope` as

```
scope :need_processing, -> (cutoff) { where(state: active, processed_through: cutoff.ago(1.day)) }
```

Check to `processed_through` between two query in Rails 3.2 and Rails 4.0.

Comment: Is this correct way

scope :need_processing, -> (cutoff) { where(state: active, "processed_through <?" => cutoff.ago(1.day)) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope :need_processing, ->(cutoff) {where("state = 'active' and processed_through < ?", cutoff.ago(1.day))}`